# Характеристики распределений случайных величин

Tags: теория-вероятностей

читаю книгу и там написано следующее:

ГСЧ должен выдавать близкие к следующим значения статистических параметров, характерных для равномерного случайного закона:
0,5 — математическое ожидание;
0,0833 — дисперсия;
0,2887 — среднеквадратичное отклонение.

Откуда получено такое мат ожидание не объясняют. Может кто знает как получить? И как получить для других распределений подобные характеристики. Спасибо.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он явно не по теме.

Comment: Тег вопроса "теория вероятностей" Правильнее по моему мнению было бы "статистика" или "статистический анализ", но в принципе - вопрос не крамольный, а вполне интересный для новичков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мат.ожидание [для случайной величины с равномерным распределением равно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)

`(a + b) / 2`, где а - нижняя граница, b - верхняя граница.

Подставив 0 и 1 (именно в этих границах обычно работают ГСЧ) в формулу получим 0,5.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, что написаноми в какой книге, но дело в том, что у "правильного" равномерного распределения значения моментов первого, второго - да и высших - порядков вполне определенное, а именно - среднее=медиана=(a+b)/2, дисперсия = (1/12)*(b-a)**2, асимметрия =0, а эксцесс = -6/5. Где a и b - заданные границы распределения.
Объяснения - и доказательства - в соответствующих учебниках.

Соответственно "правильный" ГСЧ должен генерировать выходную последовательность таким образом, что бы ее значения удовлетворяли указанным соотношениям.